# how to use grep to match partial occurrence of searched string

Tags: grep, tcl

my text file :

```
vol0 0.9 vol2 1.2 vol3 3 vol1_1 1.4 voll_2 5
vol1 1 vol2 1.2 vol3 3 vol1_1 1.4 voll_2 5
vol2 1.3 vol2 1.8 vol3 3.2 vol1_1 1.2 voll_2 4.8
....
```

How to grep lines with vol1 ,i.e only 2nd line. From what i am doing, it is taking all the three line.

Comment: *What are* you doing? And are you using grep or tcl?

Comment: Actually i was using grep inside TCL. As this issue is solved now but i got one more query regarding grep. Can i search grep with particular index number for each line, i.e in every line, look for only 3rd element and if pattern matches, grep that line.. If yes , please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want to match "vol1" as a distinct word, not "vol1_1",

With grep, use the `-w` flag (and since you're not searching for a regex, add `-F`)

```sh
grep -Fw vol1 filename
```

With Tcl, [regular expressions](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm) can include the `\y` zero-width constraint that matches at the start or end of a word:

```
set fh [open $filename r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {\yvol1\y} $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
close $fh
```

Comment: Also `string first` can be used to find literal substrings; that might be faster. (Is it actually? `time` it to find out!)

Comment: How would you use `string first` to _avoid_ matching the first line?